# multibib - hyperref doesn't work for my second bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, subdividing, multibib

I am using the `multibib` and `hyperref` packages.
I would like to create clickable citations for my bibliographies.
It works for the first one (biblio.bib) but not the second one (awebsite.bib)

Here is my minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[utf8]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{awebsite}{Another bibliography}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
The quick brown fox \cite[p.4]{article} jumps over
\cite[p.5]{articleweb} the lazy dog \citeawebsite[p.6]{articleweb}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}

\bibliographystyleawebsite{plain}
\bibliographyawebsite{awebsite}

\end{document}
```

The two BIB files (biblio.bib and awebsite.bib) are herebelow.

```
@inproceedings{article, title = "{Title}", author = "Authors", booktitle = "{BT}"}
```

...

```
@article{articleweb, author = {A}, title = "{Title2}", year = {2013}, note = {\url{URL}}}
```

And there is the result (PDF)...

---

The quick brown fox [**1**, p.4] jumps over [2, p.5] the lazy dog [2, p.6].

**References**

[1] Authors. Title. In *BT*.

**Another bibliography**

[2] A. Title2. 2013. URL.

---

The first link to References [1] is created but not the two others. Why ?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how to fix this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: The url can be in its own field url={}, instead of inside note={}, although I don't think that is the main culprit here.  Have you run latex multiple times?

Comment: Thank you for your welcome, Claudio. crypticO, yes ! I know that I have to « clean » my BIB files and remove some unnecessary brackets and quotes. Well, thanks anyway, for looking at my case. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `multibib` supports `natbib`, and `natbib` supports `hyperref`, load `natbib`, too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
  @inproceedings{article, title = "{Title}", author = "Authors", booktitle = "{BT}"}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{awebsite.bib}
  @article{articleweb, author = {A}, title = "{Title2}", year = {2013}, note = {\url{URL}}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}         %% load this, too
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{awebsite}{Another bibliography}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
The quick brown fox \cite[p.4]{article} jumps over
\cite[p.5]{articleweb} the lazy dog \citeawebsite[p.6]{articleweb}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}

\bibliographystyleawebsite{plain}
\bibliographyawebsite{awebsite}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: sample output]

Comment: Fantastic ! It works ! Thank you very much. I tried to use natbib but it didn't work. In fact, natbib must be **called before** multibib and hyperref. If not, an error « Extra \else, Use of \@citex doesn't match its definition » occurs. Thank you, thank you, thank you for your help. :)

Comment: @eddyte Yes, `hyperref` usually comes last, and `multibib` has to come after `natbib`.

Comment: I am used to classifying the packages in alphabetical order. Well, given that kind of problem, this is really a bad habit I'll try to get over. Thank you mafp. :)

Comment: Natbib changes the behavior of multibib. They are not so compatible I would say.