# Again Problems with natbib and multibib

Tags: sectioning, captions, natbib, multibib

Related to my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/590803/problems-with-multibib-and-natbib-with-defcitealias/591297#591297), which could be solved with a change in the TeXStudio configuration

`bibtex.exe -- ?*.aux`

I am still having trouble with the `natbib` and `multiref` combination.

My example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
    @book{tolkien_93,
        title={The Lord of the Rings: Part 1: The Fellowship of the Ring},
        author={Tolkien, John Ronald Reuel},
        year={1993},
        publisher={Christian Blind Mission International}
    }
    
    @book{tolkien_66,
        title={The Lord of the Rings. Part 2: The Two Towers},
        author={Tolkien, John Ronald Reuel},
        year={1966},
        publisher={Allen and Unwin}
    }
    
    @book{tolkien_55,
        title={The Lord of the Rings. Part 3: The Return of the King},
        author={Tolkien, John Ronald Reuel},
        year={1955},
        publisher={Allen \& Unwin}
    }
    
    @book{tolkien_79,
        title={The silmarillion},
        author={Tolkien, JR John Ronald Reuel},
        year={1979},
        publisher={Random House LLC}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black, 
    pagecolor=black, 
    citecolor=black, 
    filecolor=black, 
    urlcolor=black, 
    menucolor=black,
]{hyperref}

\usepackage[numbers, super, sort&compress, square]{natbib}

\makeatletter
    \def\@mb@citenamelist{cite,citep,citet,citealp,citealt,citepalias,citetalias}
\makeatother

\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{pub}{Publications}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\defcitealias{tolkien_93}{HDR-1}
\defcitealias{tolkien_66}{HDR-2}
\defcitealias{tolkien_55}{HDR-3}
\defcitealias{tolkien_79}{silmarillion}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Lipsum \protect \citepaliaspub{tolkien_93}}
    
    \lipsum[2][1]\cite{tolkien_66} \lipsum[5][7]\citepub{tolkien_93} \\ 
    \lipsum[1][2]\citepaliaspub{tolkien_79} \lipsum[25][13]\citepalias{tolkien_55}.
    
    \begin{table}[htb!]
        \centering
        \caption[short caption \protect \citepaliaspub{tolkien_93}]{caption. \protect \citepaliaspub{tolkien_93}}
        \begin{tabular}{lcc}
            \toprule
            lipsum & lipsum & lipsum \\ \midrule
            lipsum & lipsum & lipsum \\
            lipsum & lipsum & lipsum \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
        
    \bibliographystyle{angew}
    \bibliography{bib}
    
    \let\noopsort\undefined
    \let\printfirst\undefined
    \let\singleletter\undefined
    \let\switchargs\undefined   
    
    \bibliographystylepub{angew}
    \bibliographypub{bib}
    
\end{document}
```

did produce the error `Use of \mb@@citex doesn't match its definition. ...ipsum \protect \citepaliaspub{tolkien_93}}`

Is there some way to tackle this problem? The problem results from the `caption` environment, since everything works fine without it.

**EDIT 1**

As soon as I posted the question, I already found the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227833/cite-references-in-figure-caption). When using `\protect` it works fine for the `caption`, so I also tried it in the `section`, and there the error stays the same even after adding `\protect`.

**EDIT 2**

Also, I did some research and found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416399/multibib-fails-to-show-a-second-bibliography-in-the-appendix), where using `\cite<seq>` in the `\section` shows no errors using `\protect`, but for me the error
`Use of \mb@@citex doesn't match its definition. ...ipsum \protect \citepaliaspub{tolkien_93}}`
remains. Any suggestions, what I did wrong?

**EDIT 3**

When I uncomment `\usepackage{hyperref}`, `\protect` is working like it should, and, according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105718/multibib-hyperref-doesnt-work-for-my-second-bibliography), the order of the packages plays an additional role. So as soon as I find a part of the answer, another problem occurs.

Comment: @moewe Thanks, I also found this and tried it for the section environment, but this doesn't work. I changed my question according to your and my findings.

Comment: Curse you, bookmarks! Close vote retracted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hyperref has no idea what to do with `\citepaliaspub` in the bookmarks, you need to provide a sensible definition, or use

```
 \section{Lipsum \texorpdfstring{\protect\citepaliaspub{tolkien_93}}{bookmark text}}
```

A possible definition could be

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
 \def\citepaliaspub#1{\csname al@#1\@extra@b@citeb\endcsname}}
```

This would then give this in the bookmarks:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't think this would be that tricky, I have a lot more to learn. Next time maybe I will stick to biblatex ...